# darkflow calls wrong version of python

Tags: python, ubuntu-16.04, darkflow

When trying to use yolo for python I followed https://github.com/thtrieu/darkflow I got flow installed using

```
pip3 install .
```

but then, when running

```
flow --h
```

I get

```
File "/home/computername/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/darkflow/net/help.py", line 9, in <module>
import cv2
ImportError: No module named 'cv2'
```

When I call python I get into python 3.6 and if the import cv2 it does not give any problem, i.e., cv2 is imported.

When calling

```
which python
```

I get

```
/home/computername/anaconda3/bin/python
```

So flow does call the wrong version python. I thought, maybe I should delete the python 3.5 version on my computer, but looking for how to do that I only find warnings that I should not do that.

So my question is: what to do such that it will work?

maybe other relevant information:

```
which pip3
/usr/bin/pip3
```

and (I tried to install flow with pip first, but that did not work)

```
which pip
/home/bombus/anaconda3/bin/pip
```

I am working on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS